# Do I need a visa for Jamaica? I'm holding an Egyptian passport along with both Schengen and US visit visas

Tags: visas, egyptian-citizens, jamaica

Good day. I want to confirm if I can enter Jamaica using the Schengen or the US visit visa as I'm Egyptian. Egyptian citizens require a visa for Jamaica.

Comment: What research did you do? This kind of information can usually be found out quickly by Googling for official government resources. The first place to look would be the website of the Jamaican embassy in Egypt.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you still  **[need a visa](http://www.congenjamaica-ny.org/visas/requirements-2/)** for Jamaica.